# Error starting docker service

Tags: server, docker

I'm running into an error when running **sudo systemctl start docker** on a GoDaddy VPS running Ubuntu 16.4.

I installed docker following the steps for the repository: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

When I run **sudo systemctl start docker** I get the following:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**sudo systemctl status docker.service** outputs the following:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2020-03-16 00:15:47 CDT; 44s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1411 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1411 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

**sudo journalctl -xe** outputs the following:

```
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.189085256-05:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191631124-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191652077-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191662701-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191672289-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory TCP limit"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191681175-05:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191690078-05:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
dockerd[1385]: time="2020-03-16T00:15:43.191698949-05:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
dockerd[1385]: failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.425021456-05:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.427712614-05:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.427809136-05:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.427939671-05:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.428015236-05:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.429999144-05:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.430026563-05:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.430047585-05:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.430062970-05:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.431676150-05:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay2
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.433111110-05:00" level=error msg="AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems" storage-driver=aufs
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.433685934-05:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: no such device" storage-driver=overlay
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436734982-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support oom control"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436773138-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support memory swappiness"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436791630-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436813539-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support kernel memory TCP limit"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436830639-05:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436846725-05:00" level=warning msg="Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts"
time="2020-03-16T00:15:45.436861904-05:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```